$X$, $Y$, $U$, $V$ are independent on $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ with $X$, $Y$ uniform and $X+Y \sim U+V$
$X$, $Y$, $U$, $V$ are independent and valued on $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that $X$ and $Y$ are uniform and such that $X+Y\sim U+V$. On the site recently, somebody raised the question 'Are $U$ and $V$ necessarily uniform?'. Somebody else said 'yes' without details. I asked for them, but the question disappeared. Can you help me to find it again?
The question is quite interesting, since it asks essentially for the existence of non trivial polynomials $P$ and $Q$ with non negative coefficients and of degree $n-1$ such that
$$P(s)Q(s)=\frac{(1-s^n)^2}{(1-s)^2}.$$
For instance for $n=6$, $P(s)=(1+s^3)^2$ and $Q(s)=(1+s+s^2)^2$ do not fit since their degree is not $5$. For giving a counter example we have to distribute the roots of unity in a clever way and I have not been successful yet.

why can't one just take $U=0$ and $V$ distributed like $X+Y$ and independent from $X,Y$ as a counterexample? Edit: it is not possible, because $V$ has to have values in ${0,1,...,n-1}$.

@dialegou you cannot do that because $V$ is valued on ${0,1,\cdots,n-1}$

For $n=12$, we'll construct a counterexample . . .

Claim:$\;$There exist independent random variables $X,Y,U,V$, valued on $\{0,...,11\}$, such that


$X,Y$ are uniform.$\\[4pt]$
$U+V\sim X+Y$.$\\[4pt]$


but $U,V$ are not uniform.

Proof:

Let $X,Y$ be independent, uniform random variables, valued on $\{0,...,11\}$.

Let sequences $u_0,...,u_{11}$ and $v_0,...,v_{11}$ be given by
$$
\begin{array}
{|c|c|c|}
\hline
k&u_k&v_k\\
\hline
0&1&1\\
\hline
1&\sqrt{3}&2-\sqrt{3}\\
\hline
2&1&5-2\sqrt{3}\\
\hline
3&1&7-4\sqrt{3}\\
\hline
4&\sqrt{3}&10-5\sqrt{3}\\
\hline
5&1&11-6\sqrt{3}\\
\hline
6&1&11-6\sqrt{3}\\
\hline
7&\sqrt{3}&10-5\sqrt{3}\\
\hline
8&1&7-4\sqrt{3}\\
\hline
9&1&5-2\sqrt{3}\\
\hline
10&\sqrt{3}&2-\sqrt{3}\\
\hline
11&1&1\\
\hline
\end{array} 
$$
Then for both sequences, all entries are positive.

Define random variables $U,V$, valued on $\{0,...,11\}$, by
\begin{align*}
P(U=k)&=
\frac{u_k}{\sum_{i=0}^{11}u_i}
\\[4pt]
P(V=k)&=
\frac{v_k}{\sum_{i=0}^{11}v_i}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Then $X,Y,U,V$ are independent.

Define polynomials $u,v,f$ by
$$
u(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{11}u_kx^k,
\;\;\;\;\;
v(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{11}v_kx^k,
\;\;\;\;\;
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{11}x^k
$$
It can be directly verified that
$$u(x)v(x)=(f(x))^2$$
and from that identity, it follows that 
$U+V\sim X+Y$.

But clearly $U,V$ are not uniform.

Excellent.. So you have distributed the roots of  unity in a certain way, but, how did you find the ones leading to polynomials factors with positive coefficients?

@Letac Gérard: Basically brute force search.
